# Countdown from 100 to 0 with no assignations in PHP

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment, countdown

I'm having a problem figuring out an exercise my boss gave me as personal enrichment of knowledge sort of. Unfortunately I have been looking for a glimpse of answer everywhere on the web with no success and I'm now turning to you fellow programmers.

What he asked me to do is make a simple countdown from 100 to 0 (it can be displayed all at once). Easy enough so far eh? Just make a simple for loop or a while even. The problem here is that he asks that there are no assignations in the code, ex: `$[var]=[value]`.

How can one even make a loop with no assignations? Since `$i--;` is the equivalent to `$i = $i - 1;` how can we count down?

I'm baffled by this problem which I can't resolve, I really want to find the answer as I am very curious on how this can be done.

Help is kindly appreciated.

## Edit

Take note that this problem is kind of a 2 part where as the first part is to make it work 100 to 0, and in the second part x to 0 where x is inputted by the user

Comment: Hmm. Does `foreach (array(100,99,98,97) as $counter)` count as an assignation to him? That's the closest I can think of

Comment: I'd say no, but question number 2 is actually the same as number 1 but instead of 100 to 0, it's x to 0 where x is inputted by the user

Comment: That might work as `foreach (range($_POST["x"],0) as $counter)` but using `range()` feels like cheating

Comment: Probably wants you to use range

Comment: I'm gonna look into range, it seems like a plausible solution to me

Comment: Look at the examples for `range()` in the php.net documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: What about a recursive solution? That's probably the solution I'd be looking for if I were asking you to do this as a general programming problem...

Comment: @MattGibson Recursion is the answer here... Technically I think the `as` in a `foreach()` over range() is assignment.

Comment: May want to look into [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php).

Comment: The best hint I would give you is a recursive function that accepts one integer parameter (which doesn't require assignment).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Technically I'd suppose that there's "hidden assignment" in passing a function parameter, too... But I think you've got to draw the line somewhere. I'm just kind of assuming that someone trying to stretch someone else's programming skills would see more value in them learning the concept of recursion than learning about `range()`.

Comment: indeed the as is probably assignation, we can always cheat if we use print_r to "countdown" the array

Comment: @MattGibson I absolutely agree. That has to be the goal here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that your boss is trying to encourage you towards [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) rather than iteration. Recursion, as a technique, works extremely well for certain problems, and is an excellent tool to have in your armoury as a programmer.

Without giving everything away, try experimenting with defining a function that takes an argument - the "countdown" number -- and then calls *itself* in some way. You'll also need to separately kick it off by calling it once you've defined it.

Bear in mind that recursion must have some kind of termination defined, otherwise things can go very wrong. Here's an example of something going very wrong to get you started: :D

```
<?php
  function infinity() {
    print "Whoah.";
    infinity();
  }
  infinity();
```

Comment: `function f($i){
  if($i>-1){
   echo $i."<br/>";
   f($i-1);
  }
 }
 
 f(100);` I did this :D

Answer (score 4):

I will give you some hints, writing the exact code is an exercise for you.

1. No assignments, so you must have some type that can hold multiple values. Primitive types like integers cannot be used directly here, think of arrays.
2. Now, you cannot use variables, so using a loop and then printing the values is disallowed. Use one of the many ways to print an array (or the result of operating on an array).
3. The [`range()`](http://php.net/range) function does not accept a negative step value, you need to reverse the numbers.